# Udemy scraping imminents posts - Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to make a web scraper that get the URL of a post as soon as it is posted

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import requests, os

load_dotenv('.env')
id: str = os.getenv('CLIENT_ID')
password: str = os.getenv('CLIENT_PASSWORD')
header= (id, password)

r = requests.get("https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/", auth=header)
courses_list = r.json()["results"]
for course in (courses_list):
    print(course)
```

How can I print new courses while the program is still running?